# Ruby on Rails - Forum moderator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building simple image-board type site.

There is no need for registration because users are anonymous.

Problem is that I don't know how to add moderators.

I cant make form for registration because then regular users could register and be able to delete posts.

Comment: This is the wrong place for this post.

Comment: you could have login users but dont display any of there info and keep it animus. And you could have a login for moderators

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a combination of a registration system like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to handle your user accounts and an authorization system like [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) which can establish permissions.